# Mocha keeps bombing due to absolute paths

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm having a great deal of trouble using Enzyme and Mocha to test my React project. I have a test like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { ChipInput} from '../client/components/Chips';

describe('<ChipInput />', _ => {
  it('rocks', done => {
    done();
  });
});
```

And when `ChipInput` gets imported, that file imports something with an absolute path, e.g. `/lib/collections/tags`, and then Mocha errors out because it apparently only does relative paths. How do I get this working?

EDIT:

The actual error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/lib/collections/tags'
```

This happens because `/tests/ChipInput-test.js` imports the `ChipInput` component from `/client/components/Chips/index.js`, which has the following lines:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  MapsLocalOffer as TagIcon,
  ImageRemoveRedEye as InsightIcon,
  EditorInsertChart as TestIcon,
  SocialPerson as UserIcon,
} from 'material-ui/svg-icons';

import { Tag } from '/lib/collections/tags'; // error thrown here
import { Insight } from '/lib/collections/insights';
// import { Test } from '/lib/collections/tests';
import Chip from './Chip';
import ChipDisplay from './ChipDisplay';
import ChipInput from './ChipInput';
import * as chipTypes from './chip-types';
```

Comment: It would likely help to see the error you are getting.

Comment: Can you show us your "ChipInput" component?

Comment: I don't think we can know what's happening if you dont show us your whole "ChipInput" component and your "Tag" library.

Comment: The component itself is irrelevant, trust me. It's hitting that `import` statement and throwing an error. It's not even getting that far.

Comment: @QoP I added more lines from the `index.js` file. Definitely all the info that's needed. Again, it's not even getting past the `import { Tag }` line.

Comment: I've got the same issue

Comment: @Tom See my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, nice and simple!

https://github.com/mantrajs/babel-root-slash-import

Basically, install said package:

```
npm install babel-root-slash-import --save-dev
```

Add the plugin to `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-root-slash-import"
  ]
}
```

And it's good to go.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12384327)

Comment: @Daniel Point taken. Edited. If you're the one who downvoted and flagged for deletion, please consider removing your downvote.

Comment: looks promising, i'll try it out tomorrow :)

Comment: @ffxsam this doesn't work for me. do I need to add anything to my `test` script? currently: `"test": "mocha --require ignore-styles setup.js --compilers js:babel-core/register 'client/**/*.spec.js'",`

Comment: Doesn't do anything. It sounds like you'd have to switch from using Node anywhere to using babel-node, but I'm not sure what that entails and the answer didn't even mention it (author was probably already using babel-node).

Answer (score 3):

To anyone hitting here from google, while ffxsam's answer will work, there are many ways to accomplish this. Node's require allows for a base to be set either via environment variable or programmatically, allowing for simple absolute paths that don't require the leading slash (`require("my/module");` vs `require("/my/module");`).

I use gulp as a taskrunner, so my preferred technique is to use `app-module-path` to do the following at the top of my gulpfile (this will work anywhere, so long as you haven't encountered any absolute `require`s yet):

```
require('babel-core/register'); //for mocha to use es6

require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname + '/src'); //set root path

//I also use webpack to pull in other extensions, so I
//want mocha to noop out on them
require.extensions['.css'] = _.noop;
require.extensions['.scss'] = _.noop;
require.extensions['.png'] = _.noop;
require.extensions['.jpg'] = _.noop;
require.extensions['.jpeg'] = _.noop;
require.extensions['.gif'] = _.noop;
```

For a more complete rundown, check out this gist by github user branneman: https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Answer (score 3):

This has been awhile, but I want to share my solution here, just in case, all solutions above don't work in your specific situation. I was looking for a solution to fix our unit test, which failed "Error: Cannot find module 'components/shared/xyz', our 'components' folder is under 'client/src' folder, so I came up with the following solution which works for us.

```
npm install babel-plugin-module-resolver --save-dev

{
  'plugins': [
      'babel-plugin-module-resolver',
      { 'root': ['client/src'] }
   ]
}
```